# DetailTextLabel is not display in iOS 8 xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, cell, detailtextlabel

I making the tutorial on running iPhone 5S, Xcode 6 and iOS 8. I want to display the textDetailLabel in a cell table. Can you help me what's the problem here. I already checked the syntax but it doesn't work

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
Checklist *checklist = [self.dataModel.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = checklist.name;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

int count = [checklist countUncheckedItems];
if ([checklist.items count] == 0) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"(No Items)";
} else if (count == 0) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"All Done!";
} else {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Remaining", count];
}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Once comment all the if conditions and check.

Comment: This is a bug in iOS8. I dont know any workaround. only with default cell. I have used custom cell instead of default one.

Comment: tks Anil, I just found the issue! Is there any way to do without using the custome cell ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Move

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

out of the method, make it public.

2. When you create the table view write this line where you create the table (in viewDidLoad or your method where you create the table)

`[dataTable registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];`

3. Remove cell condition from

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

method because your table view cell is not nil and you can't set the cell style.

So you have to write

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```